# Is it good to have 100+ threads running in a windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I am writing a windows service which is synching 2 servers. I wrote the service in such a way that there is a thread for every user in the servers. So in each thread the Service does polling to Server 1 asking for changes and pushes the changes to Server2. This works fine but I am not happy with the approach when considering the number of users that I may have to deal with. Is it safe/appropriate to run 100+ threads in a windows service ?

I know this question is of pure opinion but let me know your opinion.

Thanks,
Sujith

Comment: Is it safe/appropriate to run 100+ threads in a service? Perhaps.  100 threads, one for each user?  Yes, it won't scale.  It's arguably a bad idea to spin up another thread that will ultimately block on I/O (including network) waiting for something to happen.  Better to recycle it to serve multiple simultaneous requests.  Google _IOCP_

Comment: @MickyD: Thanks for your comment. I have already started looking into IOCP. I was also thinking to run a single thread which will poll for the changes for each users sequentially. ofcourse this will cause a small delay in synch depending on the number of users it has to iterate through.

Comment: Where possible, switch to using async mechanisms and stop manually dealing with threads at all - don't think, single-threaded nor thread-per-user. Just kick off work and use whatever mechanisms are appropriate to deal with when the async work has completed (be it await, callbacks, etc, depending on what async mechanism you're working with)

Comment: The simple answer is "No". The complicated answer is, "No - that approach doesn't scale". Remember that each thread gets a stack, and needs additionally to be tracked by the kernel's thread scheduler. Creating orders of magnitude more threads than CPU cores impacts system performance for all applications for no benefit.